# Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string, w

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I know this has been asked before but can't find a answer to my specific instance of this error.

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string
```

Here is my code:

```
try 
{
    // create connection and set error attributes
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . HOST . "; dbname=" . DATABASE, USER, PASS);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    //define insert and query variables

    $query = "SELECT * FROM cart WHERE user_id=? AND product_id=?;";

    $insert = "INSERT INTO cart (user_id, product_id, qty, date) 
            VALUES ('$sessId', :i, :q, 'Now()');";

    // execute a query to check if item all ready exist in cart
    $r = $conn->prepare($query);
    $r->execute(array(
        session_id(),
        $i
    ));

    if ($r->rowCount() > 0) {
        echo 'Item already exists in cart';
    } else {
        $q = $conn->prepare($insert);
        $q->bindParam(':i', $i);
        $q->bindParam(':q', $q);

        $q->execute();
        header('Location:../shopping_cart.php');

    }
    $r->closeCursor();


}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

I cant find anything wrong with it, otherwise I just need to know what I need to do to get the values to convert, or should I look into another method.

Comment: Why are you trying to pass $sessId in the string instead of binding a parameter?

Comment: Can't find the error, there is any message of error?

Comment: And... why you test your cart with `session_id()` but insert with $sessId ?

Comment: You should put the error message along with the line on which it occurs in the body of your question. Not only in the title.

Comment: Its just what I was trying to eleminate which parameter was causing the the error, because it was all working until I added the binding params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the name of variable `$q`, you are changing type for nothing.

```
$q = $conn->prepare($insert);
$q->bindParam(':i', $i);
$q->bindParam(':q', $q); //binding a prepare statement itself?
```

Change to, and define the `$qty` with initial value of `$q`.

```
$q = $conn->prepare($insert);
$q->bindParam(':i', $i);
$q->bindParam(':q', $qty);
```

Answer (score 1):

First you are testing if there is at least one record using

```
session_id()
```

If not then you are trying to insert with

```
$sessId
```

Assuming that they somehow have the same value...

I think you should insert with real prepared statement like:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO cart (user_id, product_id, qty, date) 
           VALUES (:s, :i, :q, :n);";
         ...
         ...
         ...
 $q = $conn->prepare($insert);
      $q->bindParam(':s', $sessId);
      $q->bindParam(':i', $i);
      $q->bindParam(':q', $qty);
      $q->bindParam(':n', Now());

      $q->execute();
      header('Location:../shopping_cart.php');
```

Comment: You missed the major issue ->  `$q->bindParam(':q', $q);`. Notice how the OP is binding the PDO object `$q` as a param?